# Laravel 4: Caching JSON Response

Tags: php, caching, memcached, laravel, laravel-4

I'm totally new to Laravel, and i need to cache a JSON response every 60 min. Saw that Laravel offers lots of caching modules: File, Redis, Memcached, APC.. Which one would suite best for my need? I've red that Memcached and APC are the fastest.

And another thing, when i define caching

> Cache::put('key', 'value', $minutes);

should be defined inside Controller or Model?

Comment: The easiest option would be file, otherwise you will have to install the extension for memcached.

Comment: But memcached would be faster? I don't want the easiest way, i want the best way. Problem is can't find good documentation or tutorials for this.

Comment: Yes memcached would be faster, so use that if speed is your main concern (we are talking about miliseconds here).

Comment: I think i'll go with file caching, i don't have direct access to server and that could be a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a big difference in caching to a file system or memcached. Memcached has many advantages but keep in mind that the data is stored in the memory, while files are stored on the hard drive, which is much cheaper.

I would say if you're building a smaller site, with not so much traffic, file caching is the better way to go. You want feel the difference that much on sites like that, so no need to over-optimize because of a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll go with file caching system. Just another thing, in Laravel where do you define caching method, in Controller?

Comment: I would put anything data related inside the model. The controller just passes the result from the model to the view.